# How to write on XML file an indented text (php)

Tags: php, xml, dom, indentation

I would like to add a new node to an XML file stored on disk.This part is ok, I've solve it :

```
                        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
                        $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
                        $xml->formatOutput = TRUE;
                        $xml->load($fichier);

                        ...
                        $rootTag->insertBefore($annonce,$rootTag->firstChild);
                        $xml->save($fichier);
```

Initial XML :

```
<genevecrb>
<annonce id="149">
        <flagplus/>
        <entete>GENEVE</entete>
        <nouveau>1</nouveau>
        <description>EN EXCLUSIVITÉ SUPERBE RESTAURANT EN SA</description>
        <couleur>R</couleur>    
        <detail>90 places intérieur et TERRASSE privative de 80 places&lt;br/&gt;
                CA 1'500'000.--&lt;br/&gt;
                PV sur demande et sur rdv. Possibilité de crédit si 70% fonds propres (env. 530'000.--)&lt;br/&gt;
                Hyper opérationnel et entièrement refait à neuf. Bail 10 années renouvelable de 10 années.&lt;br/&gt;
                Loyer 5'100.-- avec parkings et chauffage.&lt;br/&gt;
                Dossier confidentiel.
        </detail>
        <autre/>
        <contact>Pour tout renseignement nous contacter</contact>
        <vente>REMIS</vente>
</annonce>
```

After adding new node :

```
<genevecrb><annonce id="150"><flagplus/><entete>Ceci est un message</entete><nouveau/><description>Le message de description</description><couleur/><detail>Le bla bla bla</detail><autre>Autre r&amp;eacute;sine</autre><contact>Contact</contact><vente>Vente</vente></annonce>
<annonce id="149">
        <flagplus/>
        <entete>GENEVE</entete>
        <nouveau>1</nouveau>
        <description>EN EXCLUSIVITÉ SUPERBE RESTAURANT EN SA</description>
        <couleur>R</couleur>    
        <detail>90 places intérieur et TERRASSE privative de 80 places&lt;br/&gt;
                CA 1'500'000.--&lt;br/&gt;
                PV sur demande et sur rdv. Possibilité de crédit si 70% fonds propres (env. 530'000.--)&lt;br/&gt;
                Hyper opérationnel et entièrement refait à neuf. Bail 10 années renouvelable de 10 années.&lt;br/&gt;
                Loyer 5'100.-- avec parkings et chauffage.&lt;br/&gt;
                Dossier confidentiel.
        </detail>
        <autre/>
        <contact>Pour tout renseignement nous contacter</contact>
        <vente>REMIS</vente>
</annonce>
```

The new node is inline and not indented.
PreserveWhiteSpace and formatOutput don't work.
How can I indent that? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

XML is an abstraction of a graph. Depending on the API you're using,  whitespace like tabs and newlines can be actually treated as `TextNode`s. If you mix your whitespace with elements, that has a meaning in XML, but some parsers ignore whitespace if it is not part of a text. This creates the impression that there is no text between the elements.

That said your indentation comes from additional nodes which you are not adding - and you shouldn't, really. Use your library's "pretty printing" function to save the document, or run a formatter on the file after you saved it.